# Can a PC connect to more than one Windows Phone 7 device simultaneously?

Tags: windows-phone, connection

Can a PC connect to more than one Windows Phone 7 device simultaneously? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  think you can't. Only to first connected device you can deploy application.

This question was discussed before: [Connect multiple (two) windows phones to the computer at the same time and develop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516354/connect-multiple-two-windows-phones-to-the-computer-at-the-same-time-and-devel)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Get multiple USB cords, one per device, and connect them all to the computer at once.

I'm not sure if this is what you are really asking for, though.